# Conflicto con MSDTC y Windows Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

Tengo 2 servidores (uno de aplicaciones y otro de base de datos) con `Windows Server 2008 R2` y `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

Tengo instalada una aplicación desarrollada con C# .NET Framework 2.0 y 2 Bases de Datos, hago uso de `TransactionScope` para manejar `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete`, si yo ejecuto estas operaciones en una sola Base de Datos todo termina perfecto pero si yo ejecuto estas dos operaciones en las 2 bases de datos comienzo a tener problemas con `TransactionScope`.

Este conflicto no se presenta si instalo mi aplicación en el mismo servidor que el de Base de Datos. Ya ejecuté una configuración de `MSDTC` en ambos servidores pero no puedo resolver mi problema, tengo el Firewall activo, no se si esto también causa conflicto.

A continuación agrego un ejemplo del código que utilizo para mis operaciones a BD, este código lo tengo en un método llamado EjecutaVenta de la clase VentaManager:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{

    //El objeto ventasPorUnidadBD ejecuta un insert en la Base de datos "A"
    ventasPorUnidadBD.Insert(objVentas);

    //El objeto inventarioBD ejecuta un update en la Base de datos "A"
    inventarioBD.UpdateInventario(objVentas);

    //El objeto solicitudVentaBD ejecuta un update en la Base de datos "A"
    solicitudVentaBD.Delete(objSolicitudVenta);

    //El objeto movimientoPorMesBD ejecuta un update en la Base de datos "B"
    movimientoPorMesBD.Insert(objVentas);

    //El objeto bitacoraSistemaBD ejecuta un update en la Base de datos "B"
    bitacoraSistemaBD.Insert(objBitacora);

    //Hacer Commit a la transacción
    scope.Complete();
```

}

Al ejecutarse la excepción, se genera elsiguiente registro en mi archivo de log:

*(13/06/2017 08:03:37 p.m.)MovimientoPorMesBD.Insert();  - The transaction has already been implicitly or explicitly committed or aborted.*

*(13/06/2017 08:03:37 p.m.)VentaManager.EjecutaVenta();  - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Espero puedan ayudarme con este problema.

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Buenas, pudiera ser de ayuda si concretaras un poco cuales son esos problemas que empiezas a tener. P.D: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, no se te olvide pasar por el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Qué tal, gracias por responder. Entre los conflictos que se me presentan están el hecho de que las operaciones a Base de Datos no terminan su ejecución, por ejemplo, si tengo 5 updates, no se ejecutan todos ni llego al fin de la transacción, en el log de mi aplicación se registra un mensaje indicando el error, si recuerdo bien es este "The transaction has already been implicitly or explicitly committed or aborted". Gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Con esa excepción (que sugiero añadas a la pregunta) puede ser realmente cualquier cosa, pero queda claro que la transacción se ha "perdido" o terminado prematuramente. Sería de interés tener algo más de información (si fuera posible, claro). Podrías ponernos el trozo de código que carga y confirma las operaciones en el `TransactionScope`? Si pudieras indicarnos la línea del error sería de ayuda también.

Comment: Qué tal amigo, muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda, he editado la pregunta agregando la porción de código donde tengo un ejemplo de una de las operaciones que me causan conflicto, además de un ejemplo del registro en el archivo de Log donde detallo el error identificado, espero esto sea de ayuda. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: En principio, según código todo debería funcionar más aún si tenemos en cuenta que _"Este conflicto no se presenta si instalo mi aplicación en el mismo servidor que el de Base de Datos"_ . Por lo que reducimos todo a un problema de comunicación. No es que no me fíe pero puedes confirmar que el `MSDTC ` está correctamente configurado tanto para **transación entrante** como para **transacción saliente**? Por otro lado el Firewall podría estar molestando, añade reglas de excepción (o desactivalo para hacer la prueba)

Comment: Hola @DanMen, ¿como estás gestionando las conexiones a las bases de datos? Para que las conexiones se "enlisten" a la transacción, se deben de abrir dentro del `TransationScope`, si las conexiones ya están abiertas, hay que "enlistarlas" manualmente con `connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current)`

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, el conflicto inicial ha sido solucionado con la configuración para transacción entrante y transacción saliente (me faltó únicamente marcar ambas opciones en ambos servidores), ya puedo ejecutar las operaciones a diferentes bases de datos, sin embargo, todo esto le lleva demasiado tiempo, aproximadamente 40 segundos de mas pero únicamente para ese caso (si yo ejecuto la operación para una sola BD esto no sucede así) y no me genera ningún registro de error  ¿Es esto normal y si no lo es, tienes alguna idea de qué pueda estar pasando?

Comment: Hola @rsciriano muchas gracias por responder, efectivamente, tengo mis conexiones tal y como lo especificas.